# does mysql move on to the next row if a condition within its query is not met?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I'm wondering about the order of Mysql operations when performing a query.
For example, if I have a query like:

```
select * from Posts where year>2016 and name like '%A%' and veryExpensiveFunction(this,that) and age>12;
```

does mysql move on to the next row if the first condition is not met (year>2016) or does it determine the result of all its conditions and then say 'whoops... condition #1 wasn't even met... so move on to the next row'.  It seems like if I had a very expensive function within my conditions, I'd want to put it last.

What is your take.  I would like to think it just evaluates each condition in a big 'and' chain one by one... and if they aren't met... it moves on

Comment: well how would you know if there isn't element that has year column set to greater than 2016 if you don't go through every row ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, what you are looking for is the query plan. MySQL has an Explain statement that will tell you how it evaluates a particular statement. There is no simple answer to how an RDBMS will evaluate even a simple query, as a lot depends on whether there are indexes on the columns in the criteria, and other factors such as the final sort order. I don't have a MySQL server handy so I can't provide an example, but the output from 'Explain' will tell you if (for example) there is an index on the year column which is being used to filter for 'year > 2016' before the other criteria are applied.